# AJAX - Replace HTML Select Menu with Result from PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 select menus on my form: Type and Category. When a user selects something from the Type menu I want it to then perform a PHP script which queries a database and returns a list of matching categories for the selected Type for them to choose from in the Category menu.

Here's my HTML for the 2 select menus:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="control-label col-sm-3" >Type</label>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
                <select class="form-control" name="type" id="type">
                <option value="" selected></option><option value="Business">Business</option><option value="Commercial">Commercial</option><option value="Commercial Land">Commercial Land</option><option value="Land">Land</option><option value="Rental">Rental</option><option value="Residential">Residential</option><option value="Rural">Rural</option>                 </select>
            </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="control-label col-sm-3" >Category</label>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-8" class=""id="categoryList">
                <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
                <option value="" selected></option>                 </select>
            </div>
    </div>
```

The script has some issue that I can't track down - I'm learning all this as I go. Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#type").change(function(){
        var type = $("#type").val();
        $.post('getPropertyCategories.php', { type: type }, function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
            if (data.error) {
                $("#categoryList").addClass("has-error");
                $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-danger").html(data.text);
                $("#ajaxAlert").show();
                return; // stop executing this function any further
            } else { 
                $('#category').html(data);
                $("#categoryList").addClass("has-success");
                $("#categoryList").removeClass("has-error");
                // if you want to show a success alert enable the following
                // $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-success").html(data.text);
                $("#ajaxAlert").hide();
            }

        }).fail(function (xhr) {
            // no data available in this context
            $("#categoryList").addClass("has-error");
            $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-danger");
            //display AJAX error details
            $("#ajaxAlert").html(xhr.responseText);
            $("#ajaxAlert").show();
        });
     }); 
});
```

It does call the PHP script but the Category select menu doesn't get updated. Looking at the console I'm getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'
```

for this line:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

I feel like I'm pretty close but can't work out what the issue is.

Comment: Is your PHP script returning raw HTML?

Comment: Precisely what I was going to ask, this error is usually thrown because you're trying to parse HTML.

Comment: Yes you are right - if successful it's returning the HTML to show the select menu. Any suggestions around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data need to be json encoded when you call JSON.parse().

In your getPropertyCategories.php get rid of code which is printing out categories in html, and encode your query result as json:

```
$categories = json_encode($queryForTypeResult);
```

set headers and return data:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
return $categories;
```